# return string from multiline between two digit values in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that can span multiple lines. I would like to append the string part at the end of the line. The string is between two digit values

For example:

```
567899|190.78.9|xmp  
xmyz  
lpz  
dwx  
765423|195.9.0|nnox  
wertx  
wz  
89021|199.6.7|xxz
```

Desired output:

```
567899|190.78.9|xmp xmyz lpz dwx 
765423|195.9.0|nnox wertx wz
```

Kindly assist on how to do this in c#.
I tried the code below but it only prints the lines starting with digits and omits the strings in multiline

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path2))
{                    
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d+"))
    {
        File.AppendAllText(path2 + "mfile2.txt", line + Environment.NewLine);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Using regex to find following pattern, "(new_line)(A-Za-z)(new_line)" and then replace it with "(A-Za-z)"

Comment: Your regex only is looking for one chunk of numbers.  You'd probably do better to split by | and pull out the string values - as this looks like 3 records 2 have multiline comment 1 does not

Comment: you want to append xmyz (new line) lpz (new line) dwx to xmp on the first line so you will get 567899|190.78.9|xmp xmyz lpz dwx (new line) wmyz ... /.?

Comment: yeah. I want it to be 567899|190.78.9|xmp xmyz lpz dwx then newline then 765423|195.9.0|nnox wertx wz then newline etc

Comment: An `else` somewhere might be a good idea. And trace it through so that you see what is happening.

Comment: i already tried with and else. It prints each string on its own line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to replace the newline with an empty string (or your desired separator) when the next character after the newline is not a digit. You can do this with a one line regex as long you are using the Multiline option:

```
var original = 
@"567899|190.78.9|xmp  
xmyz  
lpz  
dwx  
765423|195.9.0|nnox  
wertx  
wz  
89021|199.6.7|xxz";

var replaced = Regex.Replace(original, @"\r\n(?:[^\d])", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

output:

```
567899|190.78.9|xmp  myz  pz  wx   
765423|195.9.0|nnox  ertx  z  
89021|199.6.7|xxz
```

You can tweak the regex to get rid of any superfluous whitespace characters:

```
Regex.Replace(original, @"\s*\r\n(?:[^\d])", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well but all the answers through out of memory error if file is more than 300mb

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

Basically, you put the current line into a buffer. If the next line starts with a digit, then send the buffer to the output file and clear it. If the next line doesn't start with a digit, then append it to the buffer and continue reading. At the end of the loop, you will be left with the last line in the buffer, and you need to send that to the output file as well.

```
string buffer = string.Empty;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path2))
{                    
    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"^\d+"))
    {
        if (buffer != string.Empty) 
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path2 + "mfile2.txt", buffer + Environment.NewLine);
            buffer = string.Empty;
        }
        buffer = line;    
    } else {
        buffer += " " + line;
    } 
}
if (buffer != string.Empty) 
{
    File.AppendAllText(path2 + "mfile2.txt", buffer + Environment.NewLine);   
}
```